# Error when running ionic cordova run ios - seems to be related to push notification

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]
I am trying to test cordova-plugin-firebase in my ionic v1 project.

I am getting an error when running

```
ionic cordova run ios
```

If I run the command

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

I don't get any error message.  Also, ***if I open the project in Xcode and try to run the app in a simulator(iphone 8), it successfully runs*** but running the app in xcode with a device (iphone 4s) connected also shows the same error when running

```
ionic cordova run ios.
```

The error I am getting is "Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "nativeApp" target's entitlements. Automatic signing can't add the aps-environment entitlement to your provisioning profile"

I saw that one of the solution to this problem is to enable push notification under your "target > capabilities".  But I can't seem to find this option in Xcode when I'm in the project navigator.  I am currently using XCode 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this both :-

Under Code Signing Identity, change iPhone Distribution to iPhone Developer for Debug section.
 push notifications :- go Target-> Capabillities and turned on push notifications.

Comment: code signing is already set to Developer.  for the Target->Capabilities, that is my problem - I don't know where to find this option.  It does not appear to be available in Xcode 9.1

Comment: first click on folder icon for project files -> first project blue icon .it will show different tabs with Capabilities option.

Comment: found it!  Thanks a lot.  I managed to fix the problem by turning on the push notification.