# Adding aps-environment entitlement to UITest Target in Xcode

Tags: xcode, testing, apple-push-notifications, ui-automation, xcuitest

I am testing an app that uses Push notifications.  Within the main app target, the 'Push Notifications' (inside the Capabilities tab) is set to on.

I created a UITest target for UI Automation Testing.  UITest targets do not contain a 'Capabilities' tab so I am unable to set this target to use push notifications.  When I try and Automatically manage signing, I get the following error message:

"Automatic signing can't add the aps-environment entitlement to your provisioning profile. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile form the developer website."

The trouble is the Xcode managed provisioning profiles do not seem to appear in the Developer Portal anymore.

Does anyone know a way round this?  Is there perhaps a build setting within the UITest Target that I can set to add the aps-environment entitlement (instead of using the Capabilities tab).

PS - looking online all accepted answers for this error are to switch on Push notifications in the 'Capabilities' tab (something we don't have in the UITest target):
e.g. [Error when running ionic cordova run ios - seems to be related to push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652070/error-when-running-ionic-cordova-run-ios-seems-to-be-related-to-push-notificat)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed this by removing the need for entitlements from the XCUITest Target.  Here are the details:

Selected the UITest target >
Went to the UITest 'Build Settings' tab >
Searched for 'Code Signing Entitlements' > 
Removed all entitlement values here (since only removing them from the XCUITest target not the app itself)

This fixed the error and allowed it to work.